# Unir documentos word docx a partir de um template e substituir palavras

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-word

Preciso pegar o conteúdo de um arquivo ***docx*** como *template*, que contém como conteúdo um texto e alguns identificadores para serem alterados com outros dados, e a partir desse *template* criar um único outro ***docx*** com o mesmo conteúdo porém replicado e com os devidos valores alterados.

Como exemplo, tenho em meu documento um texto contendo o seguinte conteúdo:

> Olá `<NOME>`! Seja bem vindo ... Seu endereço `<ENDERECO>`.

E então eu preciso criar um outro único ***docx*** contendo algo como:

> Olá `Fulano 1`! Seja bem vindo ... Seu endereço `ENDERECO 1`.
>   Olá `Fulano 2`! Seja bem vindo ... Seu endereço `ENDERECO 2`.
>   Olá `Fulano 3`! Seja bem vindo ... Seu endereço `ENDERECO 3`.

Onde cada linha seria no início de uma nova página.

Para isso estou tentando algo **(FAZENDO UM TESTE)** utilizando o plugin ***[DocX](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX)*** instalado no projeto via ***NuGet***.
**Uma outra forma de realizar o processo será bem vinda!**

Meu exemplo para apresentação do problema:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("Fulano 1", "Endereco 1");
    dictionary.Add("Fulano 2", "Endereco 2");
    dictionary.Add("Fulano 3", "Endereco 3");

    var template = new FileStream("D:\\template.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var docs = new List<DocX>();

    var x = 0;
    foreach (var item in dictionary)
    {
        x++;
        var doc = DocX.Create("D:\\temp_NUM.docx".Replace("NUM", x.ToString()));
        doc.ApplyTemplate(template, true);
        doc.ReplaceText("<NOME>", item.Key);
        doc.ReplaceText("<ENDERECO>", item.Value);
        doc.Save();
        docs.Add(doc);
    }

    var newDoc = DocX.Create("D:\\newDoc.docx");
    foreach (var doc in docs)
        newDoc.InsertDocument(doc);

    newDoc.Save();
}
```

Apesar de estar usando uma fonte de dados simples, construída com um `Dictionary`, a origem dos dados será do banco de dados do sistema onde isso deve ser implementado.

Os arquivos **temp_1.docx**, **temp_2.docx** e **temp_3.docx** são criados e o conteúdo aparece corretamente.
Mas na linha `newDoc.InsertDocument(doc);` em:

```cs
foreach (var doc in docs)
    newDoc.InsertDocument(doc);
```

Obtenho o seguinte erro: **A sequência não contém elementos**. E com isso o "merge" não é feito.

**Como posso resolver o problema?**

Comment: Hum... parece algo bem simples (e você não mencionou se os dados têm uma origem específica além de manualmente informados). Sendo assim, por que você simplesmente não usou o recurso de [Mala Direta em Diretório](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294693/pt-br) nativo do MS Word?

Comment: O link do meu comentário anterior tem as informações, mas você acha tutoriais [como esse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqBMw_IGr-E) no Youtube que fazem passo a passo. Não achei um tutorial em português, mas o que ele está fazendo você acha na aba "Correspondências", botão "Iniciar Mala Direta", opção "Assistente de Mala Direta Passo a Passo".

Comment: De todas as formas, a minha pergunta era mais no sentido de por que você está tentando desenvolver algo pra isso. Há algum motivo adicional (como, por exemplo, você ter um número grande de arquivos docx e por isso desejar automatizar o processo)? Se sim, talvez seja mais fácil usar a API do Office, como sugerido em uma resposta, ou ainda o [tag:vba] diretamente do Word...

Comment: Desculpe, mas não está claro. Exigência de que software? Qual é realmente essa exigência? Porque, como eu disse, fazer isso que você pede na pergunta (e até mesmo enviar por email ou imprimir) é algo que o MS Word JÁ FAZ sem precisar implementar nada. Vide esse outro vídeo aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUPmA8e549s

Comment: Fui eu quem votou negativamente na questão, porque acho que ela está mal formulada. Apesar de bem escrita, a forma como você está pedindo não faz sentido (pelo menos pra mim), porque o seu "sistema" está gerando mala direta usando o Word, que já faz isso sozinho. Tentei perguntar pra entender melhor (ou te fazer melhorar a questão nesse sentido), mas os argumentos "é claro que preciso disso" e "meu software tem que fazer isso" não são realmente úteis para a comunidade porque simplesmente não descrevem a sua real necessidade. Eis a motivação do meu voto negativo.

Comment: Se você tentar melhorar a pergunta, eu prometo que ao menos tiro o meu voto negativo. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14950/discussion-between-luiz-vieira-and-tremdoido).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu usaria a API do Office disponibilizada pela própria Microsoft, e então:

```
    wordApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
    oDoc = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;

    oDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("c:\....");
```

Dê uma lida no site da Microsoft, vai encontrar tudo o que precisa sobre isso.

Com essa ferramenta você pode desde adicionar macros (VB) até fazer o *merge*.

Muito, muito tempo atrás eu fiz uma dll para um projeto pessoal (http://pastebin.com/kDZVhpiz) que pode te ajudar.. não julgue o código kk eu tinha 15 anos ainda, mas pode te servir como um guia.

Answer (score 2):

Há [uma discussão na página do desenvolvedor](https://docx.codeplex.com/discussions/346270) em que explicam que este método não está bom e que não deve ser usado.

Eu partiria [pra outro package](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=DOCX). Este aqui me pareceu bem promissor: http://www.nuget.org/packages/TemplateEngine.Docx

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo utilizando a biblioteca [`DocX`](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX).

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string templatePath = @"D:\\template.docx";
    string newFile = @"D:\\newDoc.docx";

    var template = new FileStream(templatePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    string[] aNomes = { "Fulano1", "Fulano2", "Fulano3" };
    string[] aLocais = { "Endereco1", "Endereco2", "Endereco3" };

    using (DocX doc = DocX.Create(newFile))
    {
        doc.ApplyTemplate(template, true);
        int items = aNomes.Length;
        int x = 0;
        string modelo = "";

        while (items > x)
        {
            Paragraph par = doc.InsertParagraph();
            par.AppendLine(modelo);
            par.InsertPageBreakAfterSelf();

            foreach (var p in doc.Paragraphs)
            {
                if (p.Text.Contains("<NOME>") && (p.Text.Contains("<ENDERECO>")))
                {
                    modelo = p.Text;

                    p.ReplaceText("<NOME>", aNomes[x]);
                    p.ReplaceText("<ENDERECO>", aLocais[x]);
                    x++;
                 }

             }                   
          }
          doc.Save();
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Pressione alguma tecla para sair...");
      Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Estrutura do arquivo *template.docx*:

```
--> Página 1:
    Olá <NOME>!  Seja bem vindo... Seu endereço <ENDERECO>.
```

O arquivo *newDoc.docx* deverá ficar semelhante a isto:

```
--> Página 1:
    Olá Fulano1! Seja bem vindo ... Seu endereço Endereco1
--> Página 2:
    Olá Fulano2! Seja bem vindo ... Seu endereço Endereco2
--> Página 3:
    Olá Fulano3! Seja bem vindo ... Seu endereço Endereco3
```

Acredito que isso deverá funcionar do modo que você espera.

Answer (score 1):

Essa é uma forma simples que consegui para resolver o problema:

```cs
using Novacode;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var docList = new List<string>();
        var templatePath = @"D:\template.docx";

        var fakeDAO = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        fakeDAO.Add("Fulano 1", "Endereco 1");
        fakeDAO.Add("Fulano 2", "Endereco 2");
        fakeDAO.Add("Fulano 3", "Endereco 3");

        var x = 0;
        foreach (var item in fakeDAO) {
            x++;
            var docFilePath = @"D:\temp_NUM.docx".Replace("NUM", x.ToString());
            var doc = DocX.Create(docFilePath);
            doc.ApplyTemplate(templatePath);

            doc.ReplaceText("<NOME>", item.Key);
            doc.ReplaceText("<ENDERECO>", item.Value);

            doc.Save();
            docList.Add(docFilePath);
        }
        Merge.DoMerge(@"D:\newFile.docx", docList);
    }
}
```

A classe ***Merge***:

```cs
...
public static class Merge
{
    public static void DoMerge(string newFilePath, List<string> docList)
    {
        object sectionBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
        try {
            var doc = app.Documents.Add();
            var selection = app.Selection;
            var x = 0;
            foreach (var file in docList) {
                selection.InsertFile(file);
                x++;
                if (x < docList.Count)
                    selection.InsertBreak(ref sectionBreak);
            }
            doc.SaveAs(newFilePath);
        }
        finally {
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```